# Analytic continuation of $\int_{-\infty + i \cdot p}^{\infty + i \cdot p} \exp\left[ -w^{2} +\left|w-y- i\cdot p\right|-y^{2}\right]\operatorname{d}w$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

I am dealing with the following integral defined in Eq. $(40)$. I am kind of sure that steps from Eqs. $(40)$ to $(41)$, $(41)$ to $(42)$ are both fine.

I tested on Mathematica step from Eq. $(42)$ to Eq. $(43)$ seems giving different values. But I could not pin down what is going to wrong.

I am still thinking of using analytic continuation to pull the integral contour for $w$ down from $[-\infty+ip, \infty+ip]$ to $[-\infty, \infty]$. In the other words, one can apply the residue theorem for the contour $-\infty \to \infty \to \infty+ip \to -\infty+ip \to -\infty$. This argument seems to justify that Eqs. $(42)$ and $(43)$ are indeed equal.

Anyone has idea on what is going there? Thanks a lot in advance!

$$
\begin{align*}
I\left( p, y \right) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left[ -z^{2} - 2 \cdot i \cdot p \cdot z + \left| z - y \right| - y^{2} \right] \operatorname{d}z \tag{40}\\
&= e^{-p^{2}} \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left[ -\left( z + i \cdot p \right)^{2}  + \left| z - y \right| - y^{2} \right] \operatorname{d}z \tag{41}\\
&= e^{-p^{2}} \cdot \int_{-\infty + i \cdot p}^{\infty + i \cdot p} \exp\left[ -w^{2}  + \left| w - y - i \cdot p \right| - y^{2} \right] \operatorname{d}w \tag{42}\\
&= e^{-p^{2}} \cdot \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp\left[ -w^{2}  + \left| w - y - i \cdot p \right| - y^{2} \right] \operatorname{d}w \tag{43}\\
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Where is this from as it looks incorrect?

Comment: Welcome to SE: Please write the formulas here using MathJax and don't just send a picture with the equations on it.

Comment: If you wrote the formulas from the picture yourself with a formula editor, you should look again at $(40)$ because you have more closed brackets "$]$" there than open ones "$[$".